# Wait until the page loaded Selenium Python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm opening a chrome tab with Selenium Python. I want to wait until the blue circle stops revolving. Please check the screenshot.
use case is to clock on login button and a pop up comes.
If page is still loading i.e. the blue circle is still revolving then login button does not work. I want to wait until that blue circle disappears.

[image: You can See the Marked Area]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help u:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

login_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 500).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, 'xpath of login button'))) #Waits until the login button is visible.

login_btn.click()
```

If u don't wanna find the button by its `xpath`, then u can change `By.XPATH` to `By.ID` or `By.CLASS_NAME`.

**Edit:**

Here is the complete code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe',options = chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.nike.com/es/launch/t/womens-air-jordan-6-tech-chrome')

login_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 500).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="root"]/div/div/div[1]/div/header/div[1]/section/div/ul/li[1]/button'))) #Waits until the login button is visible.

login_btn.click()
```

Output Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I tried this earlier but It did not work. I just want to wait unless all the loaded process are completed.

Comment: I have provided the complete code in the updated ans. Just copy paste the code into ur editor and check whether it works.

Comment: Thanks Sushil, as I mentioned. I tried it earlier and it worked but sometimes instead of opening login popup it was showing blank popup and I don't it's reason but still Thanks a lot for helping :)

Comment: Yes sure Sushil